# Contents under a specific 'div' is not showing in BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to fetch user comment on a blog post. The tag between which the comments lie is `<div id='loadComment> ..... </div>`.

So when I tried to view it through `soap.prettify()`, I only found `<div id='loadComment> </div>`. The codes in between were not displaying.

Below is the real code which I should be able to see as output

```html
<div id = "loadComment">
  <div>
  <div class = "comm-cont">
  <a href = "...">
  ................
    <a class = ....> ... </a>
  </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the output I get using `prettify()` is

```html
<div id = 'loadComment'>
</div>
```

I would want to fetch comments but I am not even able to view them through BeutifulSoup. Thereby, I need help from the community. Thank you in advance.

**Edit**:

url:
https://www.somewhereinblog.net/blog/nibhrita/30292259

Comment: seems to me that the website is loaded via `JS` so that' why you are unable to see the expected output.

Comment: Ow. So isn't there any fix to this particular problem?

Comment: there's always a fix, share the url.

Comment: I have edited the post and posted the url. I would like to fetch user comments from that particular blog. Thank you